# django deployed site not loading static

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, django-deployment

Perhaps I have miss understood something? I've deployed a site on my Amazon ec2 server, and it loads the page, but not the static. I've placed the "site_media" directory under the "www" directory like so:
www/site_media/static etc. And when I inspect an image element on the site, it;s URL seams to point to the right direction as `http://mysite.com/site_media/static/img/logo_text.jpg` (mysite is replaced with my site url) but when I visit the page I get a 404 page not found. Since I have debug still turned on right now, I get a list of available URLS, the one pertaining to static is `^site\_media\/media\/(?P<path>.*)$` But then it says `The current URL, site_media/static/img/logo_text.jpg, didn't match any of these.`

Here is the static in my settings.py file:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PACKAGE_ROOT, "site_media", "static")


STATIC_URL = "http://mysite.com/site_media/"


STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PACKAGE_ROOT, "static"),

]


STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
]
```

And here is how the static is added into my main urls.py file:

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Let me know if you need any additional info!

Comment: Have you run the `collectstatic` command?

Comment: Yep. The actual static files exist in the www/site_media/static/ directory. I don't know why it throws a 404 why it throws a 404 if I visit it.

Comment: Have you added 'django.contrib.staticfiles' to your installed_apps ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't you be using `STATIC_URL` and `STATIC_ROOT` in your urlpattern rather than `MEDIA_URL` and `MEDIA_ROOT`?

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: I actually ended up hosting the static files on a different server and linked that into the static URL. But I think you're right that this is the reason why it wasn't working when hosted on the same server.